# Show values from a column, using values from another column as conditions

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have a table called "fisketur" that looks like this:

[image]

I have a table called "plads" that looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it so that I only get the values from "plads.navn" that have a "plads.id" that corresponds to a specific month of the year (as found in the "fisketur" table)?

This is what I tried (getting all "plads.navn" that correspond to a "fisketur" taking place in october (month=10):

[image]

The output is correct, BUT I would like to set the the whole output column from line 92 (select plads_id from lystfisker.fisketur where month(dato)=10;) as a condition, and not have to set the output values manually as done in line 93.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Best regards.

Comment: Please share your code instead of images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `subquery` :

```
select navn 
from lystfisker.plads 
where plads_id in ( select plads_id 
                    from lystfisker.fisketur
                    where month(dato) = 10
                  );
```

Or using an `inner join`

```
select navn 
from lystfisker.plads p
inner join lystfisker.fisketur f on f.plads_id = p.plads_id
where month(f.dato) = 10
```